# Notation for a matrix populated with a Cartesian product of sets

Tags: matrices, elementary-set-theory, notation

I have several sets, e.g.

$$A_1 = \{1,2,3\}$$
$$A_2 = \{a,b,c\}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$A_P = \{\alpha,\beta\}$$

And their Cartesian product:
$$A_1 \times A_2 \times \dots \times A_P = \{(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_P) \mid  a_1 \in A_1, a_2 \in A_2, \dots, a_P \in A_P\}$$

What would be a proper way to indicate that the following matrix is populated by the ordered elements from the Cartesian product above?

$E_{N\times P} = $

\begin{bmatrix} 
  \epsilon_{1,1} & \epsilon_{1,2}  & \dots & \epsilon_{1,P}\\
  \epsilon_{2,1} & \ddots  & &\epsilon_{2,P}\\
  \vdots &   &  &\vdots\\
  \epsilon_{N,1} & \epsilon_{N,2}  & \dots & \epsilon_{N,P}\\
\end{bmatrix}

A concrete example with only the three sets above would lead to the following $18\times3$ matrix:

\begin{bmatrix} 
  1 & a  & \alpha\\
  1 & a  & \beta\\
  1 & b  & \alpha\\
        1 & b  & \beta\\
  1 & c  & \alpha\\
        1 & c  & \beta\\
        2 & a  & \alpha\\
        \vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
        3 & c  & \alpha\\
        3 & c  & \beta\\
\end{bmatrix}

I'm looking either for a mathematical expression, or a simple sentence. So far I have:

> The rows of $E_{N\times P}$ are populated by the ordered elements in the
>   Cartesian product of the sets $A_p, \forall p=1,...,P$.

But I feel that's a bit heavy and perhaps incorrect (i.e. not sure how to express the idea of "ordered elements" referring to the order in the example).